# SciFi Short Story About A Robot Caretaker and Her Ward

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, robots

I'm looking for a short story I read a couple years ago. It was about a woman (I think she was a marine biologist?) who was turned into a robot to help raise kids on an alien world. One of her kids is described as having hair like a dandelion puff a lot. Eventually some alien ocean life starts taking everybody into its hivemind. Eventually it takes her to where she reunites with her daughter. It had a lot of themes about how life always continues and death as we think of it doesn't really exist. I'm pretty sure the title has the word "remains" in it.